# How to extract the RGB values of objects in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image. I need to extract the RGB values from each object in a image.

Here is the image:

[image]

In order to extract the RGB values of each object, I need to convert the image to binary, then segment out each object.  This produces a mask that gives me where the objects are in the image.

However, once I segment out the objects, I need to convert the mask back to the original colors of each object.

How can I do that?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
img = imread('tr1.jpg');
abu=rgb2gray(img);
cb=imclearborder(abu);
thresh=graythresh(cb);
b=im2bw(cb,thresh);
bw=bwareaopen(b,60);
bwfill=imfill(bw,'holes');
label=bwlabel(bwfill,8);
max(max(label))
im1=(label==1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your problem statement correctly, you have a binary mask stored in your `bwfill` image and you want to extract out the original colours with the binary mask.  Specifically, you want to create an output image where black isn't part of the objects you want and anything non-black belong to the objects.

You can very efficiently use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for that using your `bwfill` image.  You'd use the `times` function to multiply the mask with each channel in the original image so that only the pixels that are non-zero in the mask remain.  With `bsxfun` you need to make sure that the data types between the two inputs you're multiplying with are the same type, and because `bwfill` is `logical`, you need to cast this to `uint8` before doing the multiplication.

BTW, I'm going to read your image directly from StackOverflow so that the results are reproducible:

```
%// Change
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxmma.jpg');

%// Your code
abu=rgb2gray(img);
cb=imclearborder(abu);
thresh=graythresh(cb);
b=im2bw(cb,thresh);
bw=bwareaopen(b,60);
bwfill=imfill(bw,'holes');

%// New code starts here
out = bsxfun(@times, img, uint8(bwfill));

%// Show the image
imshow(out);
```

We get this image:

[image]

---

Now that I know what you're really after (you didn't really make yourself clear...), I would advise you use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) on the binary image itself - specifically use the `BoundingBox` property, then loop over each bounding box attribute and extract out the pixels **from the segmented image** that I defined above.  However, each object will be different in size, so you should put this in a cell array.

Something like:

```
%// Apply regionprops to the binary mask
s = regionprops(bwfill, 'BoundingBox');

%// Create a cell array for the objects
objects = cell(numel(s), 1);

%// For each object...
for idx = 1 : numel(s)

    %// Get the bounding box property
    bb = floor(s(idx).BoundingBox);

    %// Extract out the object from the segmented image and place in cell array
    objects{idx} = out(bb(2):bb(2)+bb(4), bb(1):bb(1)+bb(3),:);
end
```

`objects` contains the segmented objects.  If you want to display an object, simply do:

```
imshow(objects{ii});
```

`ii` is an object you want to display from 1 up to as many as there were detected, which is `numel(objects)`.

For example, if I showed the first object, we get:

```
imshow(objects{1});
```

[image]

Comment: actually, i need to extract the rgb value of each object one by one. 
So at first, i think i have to separate it using "bwlabel" and then convert the binary object one by one using "bsxfun".

Can I do it like that? Thanks.

Comment: Use `regionprops` instead of `bwlabel` on the segmented image.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: Very nice answer as usual my friend!